# Find the number of ways to select ten distinct letters from the alphabet {A, B, C, . . . , Z} if no two consecutive letters can be selected.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have no idea how to answer this problem. Right now even my professor is a little stumped.

Comment: See - "Stars and Bars problem" on Wikipedia. This is a standard type of question.

Comment: Why did you ask this question two times? I already answered the duplicate question yesterday, didn't I?

Comment: @jvdhooft my computer is glitching out, and did not show that I ask this question yesterday. I'll just delete this one. Also I'm learning how to use this website so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 1):

The alphabet has 26 letters. If we squish the answer together as much as possible, we use up 19 spaces. (A,C,E...) So, in total, we have 7 spots of leeway. The question then becomes, with 10 places we can place these extra spots, how many ways can we move them around?

Using the technique of Stars and Bars, https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/ we change the problem to, "How many ways can we place 10 stars and 7 bars in 17 places?

17 C 10 = 19448, so I believe that would be your answer.

Comment: The answer is ${17 \choose 10} = 19448$.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed my solution.